# Select and Click iframe

Tags: c#, html, selenium, iframe

I can't select the iframe inside the webpage

Code

```
IWebElement go = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/div/div[2]/iframe[1]"));
go.Click();
```

xpath

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/div/div[2]/iframe[1]
```

Error

```
'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/div/div[2]/iframe[1]
```

Comment: The error says that XPath isn't correct.

Comment: From [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_ I've removed "C# selenium" from your title for you.

Comment: If you provide the link you are targetting, it would be much better. The XPath seems wrong and also I doubt what you want by clicking iframe.

Comment: this XPath is a copy from browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with elements within the ifame, you will need to switch WebDriver context first.

```
var iframeElement = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe")); // gets iframe from page
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeElement.GetAttribute("name")); // switch to iframe using its name

// now you can interact with elements within the <iframe> element.
```